# Binding to a static property doesn't update in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning to use MVVM in Xamarin Forms. I am stuck with a Binding issue. I have been trying different solutions on the internet for the past few hours. I am trying to bind a **static property** called `count` to the `Title` of a `Content Page`. The `Title` shows "0 PlayLists" initially. But it doesn't get updated as I add PlayLists.

Model Class

```
namespace MVVMDemo.Models
{
    public class PlayList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

        public string Title { get; set; }

        private static int count { get; set; } = 0;

        public static int Count
        {
            get { return count; }
            set
            {
                if (count == value)
                    return;

                count = value;

                OnStaticPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModel Page

```
 public void AddPlayList()
        {
            playList.Add(new PlayList
            {
                Title = string.Format("PlayList {0}", PlayList.Count + 1)
            });

            PlayList.Count++;
        }
```

XAML Page

```
<ContentPage
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo.Models"
             Title="{Binding Source={x:Static local:PlayList.Count}, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0} Playlists'}"
>
```

The count property is getting updated everytime `AddPlayList()` is run. The XAML file is not updating as the `count` changed. I have tried to use `Path` instead of `Source`. But it doesn't show anything. Please suggest me the correct syntax to use `Path` if that is the issue!

Comment: You can't use MVVM with static members. You should not be using `static` members in ViewModels anyway (except for things like `private` in-memory caching, etc). Why are you using public `static` members anyway?

Comment: As I'm learning to use MVVM, I wanted to learn how to bind static properties as well. I didn't know we can't use them at all in MVVM!

Comment: To clarify: static members can be on the ViewModel. They just don't support **dynamic** Binding. As you saw in your `x:Static` test, it **is** possible to read an **initial value** from a `static`. But it will never update. Occasionally this is useful; for example for something like "font size" that you might calculate once when an app starts on a given device, then use in many places.

Answer (score 0):

To implement data changed notify, you could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface in Xamarin.forms.

But, the static classes could not implement interface. That's why your solution would not work.

You could try the code below with `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class PlayList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private int count { get; set; } = 0;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set
        {
            if (count == value)
                return;

            count = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

With your code to binding the Count for Title, it would always be 0.

```
Model:           private static int count { get; set; } = 0;
Xaml Binding:    Title="{Binding Source={x:Static local:PlayList.Count}, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0} Playlists'}"
```

You could use the code below to get the count according to the `AddPlayList() method`.

ViewModel:

```
public class PlayListViewModel
{
    public static List<PlayList> playList { get; set; }= new List<PlayList>();

    public static int Count { get; set; }
    static PlayListViewModel()
    {
        AddPlayList();
        AddPlayList();
        AddPlayList();
    }

    public static void AddPlayList()
    {
        playList.Add(new PlayList
        {
            Title = string.Format("PlayList {0}", PlayList.Count + 1)
        });

        Count++;
    }
}
```

Xaml binding:

```
 Title="{Binding Source={x:Static local:PlayListViewModel.Count}, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0} Playlists'}"
```

For binding of static property, you could refer to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#implementing-a-navigation-menu